# How to name custom commands so that they will not be same as LaTeX commands or same as commands from packages that I may install in future?

Tags: syntax

How to name custom commands so that they will not be same as LaTeX commands or same as commands from packages that I may install in future? Maybe there some rules of naming or tips and tricks that I can use in naming of custom commands?

Comment: Add a prefix like your first name `\vsl....`

Comment: Good question. Internal macros often use a specific prefix that should be unique across packages to avoid clashes (internal macros of `etoolbox` start with `\etb@`, those of `lontable` with `\LT@`, the `@` is a common marker for internal names, macros with an `@` in the name can not be used in the document without `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`), but there is no official register of these prefixes, so uniqueness can't even be guaranteed there. Package macros for end users normally don't use a prefix, so they flow more naturally. ...

Comment: ... If you use a prefix like `\vasili` for you macros you are *probably* fine. But theoretically it is possible that you will go on to load a package that defines macros starting with `\vasili...` as well.